# (QML Calendar Example) Calendar loses ability to alter selection when custom MouseArea is added into delegate's rectangle

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to understand the inner workings of QtQuick/Calendar example.
can be found here:

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-calendar-example.html

and the  actual code is in:

https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-calendar-qml-main-qml.html

In its dayDelegate it has Rectangle that is defined like this:

```
dayDelegate: Item {


                    Rectangle {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        border.color: "transparent"
                        color: styleData.date !== undefined && styleData.selected ? selectedDateColor : "transparent"
                        anchors.margins: styleData.selected ? -1 : 0
                            }
```

I am trying to add an ability to do custom processing depending on where inside the delegate user clicks. I change the delegate to look like:

```
dayDelegate: Item {
                    Rectangle {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        border.color: "transparent"
                        color: styleData.date !== undefined && styleData.selected ? selectedDateColor : "transparent"
                        anchors.margins: styleData.selected ? -1 : 0
                        MouseArea {
                                anchors.fill: parent
                                onClicked:
                                {
                                    dayDelegateText.text  = dayDelegateText.text == "two" ? "one" : "two"

                                }
                            }
```

But once I do this, Calendar no longer reacts to clicks outside of currently selected item. **What am I breaking by adding this MouseArea?**

Even more confusing is that if I add this area inside a rectangle that is a child of delegate's rectangle and invisibly overlaps it everything works as I wanted it to and I can both operate inside a delegate and change selection.

```
dayDelegate: Item {

                    Rectangle {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        border.color: "transparent"
                        color: styleData.date !== undefined && styleData.selected ? selectedDateColor : "transparent"
                        anchors.margins: styleData.selected ? -1 : 0


                        Rectangle {
                            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                            width: styleData.selected ? parent.width/2 : 0
                            height:styleData.selected ? parent.height/2 : 0
                            color: "gray"

                            MouseArea {
                                    anchors.fill: parent
                                    onClicked:
                                    {
                                        dayDelegateText.text  = dayDelegateText.text == "two" ? "one" : "two"
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the link of the calendar example?

Comment: Valid question:)  I edited original post to include the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to visualise the `MouseArea` that you added:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

Rectangle {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Calendar {
        id: calendar
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        style: CalendarStyle {
            dayDelegate: Item {
                Rectangle {
                    id: rect
                    anchors.fill: parent

                    Label {
                        id: dayDelegateText
                        text: styleData.date.getDate()
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                        font.pixelSize: Math.min(parent.height/3, parent.width/3)
                        color: styleData.selected ? "red" : "black"
                        font.bold: styleData.selected
                    }
                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        Rectangle {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            color: "transparent"
                            border.color: "darkorange"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: visualising mouse area]

Because you have a `MouseArea` in every delegate, `Calendar`'s mouse area - a single area that covers all of the day delegates - can't get any mouse events for the areas that are taken by your `MouseArea`s.

Your third snippet works because you're only taking up half of the area of each delegate - and that's only when that particular day is selected:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

Rectangle {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Calendar {
        id: calendar
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        style: CalendarStyle {
            dayDelegate: Item {
                Rectangle {
                    id: rect
                    anchors.fill: parent

                    Label {
                        id: dayDelegateText
                        text: styleData.date.getDate()
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                        font.pixelSize: Math.min(parent.height/3, parent.width/3)
                        color: styleData.selected ? "red" : "black"
                        font.bold: styleData.selected
                    }
                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        width: styleData.selected ? parent.width / 2 : 0
                        height: styleData.selected ? parent.height / 2 : 0
                        Rectangle {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            color: "transparent"
                            border.color: "darkorange"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: third snippet screenshot]

However, it's hard to suggest a way to achieve what you're after, as you haven't told us what you're trying to do.

Comment: You are right. I am only starting to learn qml so I made an oversight that I am effectively obscuring calendar's mouse input area :) Thanks.